# How to detect Android back button in phonegap/cordova

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm currently using cordova 3.7.1. In my app I'm not able to detect the hardware back button in my jquery script. I trying out like this:
`$(document).ready(function() {
//registering the back button
 document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); });`

`function onBackKeyDown(e) {
   alert("back button pressed");//alert if the android back button is pressed
}`

But this does not work. I have tried all possibility

I have also tried to get the current URL in the MainActivity.java using

`appView.getUrl();`

But this does not return the url of the div
If I have a div as #page2 it is not returning the url.

It only returns http://sas.cer.org/index.html. Its is not returning http://sas.cer.org/index.html#page2

I'm also using jquery mobile.

Are there any alternatives for handling the android/hardware back button on the Native or on the Jquery side??

Comment: Always prefer using mobile-native events. It is a good practice to bind all mobile events in `deviceready` event.

Answer (score 4):

There are two solutions :

1) You need to include cordova.js in script tag in head section in your index html file to make the events and plugins work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

You might not be able to see this file in your folder, but the phonegap | cordova command builds it when running on mobile.

2) Modify your code as [given here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8pm5hfqu/)
Use mobile-specific events for proper functioning of your app.

Comment: I have added the cordova.js in the <head> tag. The code did not work I tried something like this:
`document.addEventListener('deviceready',function(event) {
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(e) {
        // Logic to be executed on back button event
        alert("Back Pressed");
    }
}, false);`

**Show alert if the back button is pressed**.

Comment: Here is my code snippet:
`<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(e) {
        // Logic to be executed on back button event
alert("Back Button Pressed");
    
}, false);
});
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

The following is employed and working great in an app we deploy to cordova and web.

Requires`window._cordovaNative = true` if in cordova.

I left my button handling code in there as example (see "`// close menu if open`" and other comments), which you need to replace with your code.

Put this somewhere:

```
let bNH, bakNavHandler = bNH = {
    warningOpen: false,
    init: function(){
        if (window._cordovaNative)
            document.addEventListener('backbutton', this.onback, false);
        else {
            if (!window.performance || performance.navigation.type != 1)
                this.preventDefault();
            window.onpopstate =  this.onback;
        }
    },
    preventDefault: function(e){
        window._cordovaNative ? 
            e.preventDefault() : 
            window.history.pushState(null, '', window.location.href);
    },
    onback: function(e){
        // close menu if open
        if ($('#ekapp_menu_div').css('margin-right') == '-2px'){
            bNH.preventDefault(e)
            _that.hideMenuDiv();
        }
        // close modal if open
        else if (!bNH.warningOpen && $('#ekapp_modal:visible')[0]){
            bNH.preventDefault(e)
            _that.closeModal();
        }
        // prev screen if history
        else if (_that.history.length > 1) {
            bNH.preventDefault(e)
            _that.previousScreen();
        }
        // show close app warning
        else if (!bNH.warningOpen) {
            if (window._cordovaNative)
                bNH.preventDefault(e);
            _that.openModal('Tap back button again to exit app!');
            bNH.warningOpen = true;
            $('#ekapp_modal_buttons .ekapp_cancel_btn').one('click', function(){
                bNH.warningOpen = false;
                if (!window._cordovaNative)
                    bNH.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Then in your deviceready (cordova) or doc ready (web) init function do:

```
bakNavHandler.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the doc, you have [a full example there](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton)

You have to listen for the deviceready event, not for document ready

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Back Button Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }

    // Handle the back button
    //
    function onBackKeyDown() {
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm handling the back button event on the native side itself. I'm not using OnBackKeyDown().